# Row Reduction - Spanning Vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

How can row reduction be used to determine whether n vectors in R^m span R^m? Write down a precise answer using a theorem.

So far I know that no fewer than m vectors must span R^m, so this means that the number of specified vectors will only span the given space if n=m

Comment: That last statement is not correct. Take e.g. $M=\{(1,0);(0,1);(1,1)\}$. You can easily see, that $\text{span}(M) = ℝ^2$. ($n=2, m=3$)

Comment: @J-Dorman Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

The idea is

- to span $\mathbb{R}^m$ we need $m$ linearly independent vectors
- thus in the RREF we need to find $m$ pivot that is $rank=m$ and thus $dim (Im)=m$ by [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)